# Getting value from nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, mta

I am attempting to parse through the following JSON data and console.log all the times for stop_ids of a specific value. So when I would select the stop ID "L26S", the console would log each instance that the stop time occurs within the JSON. The stop times I would like are under trip_update.stop_time_update.arrival.time.low

I have tried to use the following method unsuccessfully (feed is the name of my JSON file), I believe I'm on the right path with this but I don't know how to continue. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var feed = {
  "entity": [{
    "id": "1",
    "is_deleted": false,
    "trip_update": {
      "trip": {
        "trip_id": "009250_L..S",
        "route_id": "L",
        "start_time": null,
        "start_date": "20170512",
        "schedule_relationship": null,
        ".nyct_trip_descriptor": {
          "train_id": "0L 0132+8AV/RPY",
          "is_assigned": true,
          "direction": 3
        }
      },
      "vehicle": null,
      "stop_time_update": [{
          "stop_sequence": null,
          "stop_id": "L26S",
          "arrival": {
            "delay": null,
            "time": {
              "low": 1494569453,
              "high": 0,
              "unsigned": false
            },
            "uncertainty": null
          },
          "departure": {
            "delay": null,
            "time": {
              "low": 1494569483,
              "high": 0,
              "unsigned": false
            },
            "uncertainty": null
          },
          "schedule_relationship": 0,
          ".nyct_stop_time_update": {
            "scheduled_track": "1",
            "actual_track": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "stop_sequence": null,
          "stop_id": "L27S",
          "arrival": {
            "delay": null,
            "time": {
              "low": 1494569551,
              "high": 0,
              "unsigned": false
            },
            "uncertainty": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
}
$.each(feed.entity[0].trip_update.stop_time_update[1], function(i, v) {
  if (v.stop_id == "L02N") {
    console.log(v.arrival.time.low);
    return;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you create a working snippet to check the errors?

Comment: the json is not properly balanced

Comment: I fixed the JSON. Now there is still one error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your JSON and code access

1. You needed to access each .stop_time_update
2. Your test did not match any stop times in the JSON you gave
3. I wrapped in $(function() {}) to allow entity to be defined below the code in the snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $.each(feed.entity[0].trip_update.stop_time_update, function(_, v) {
    if (v.stop_id == "L27S") {
      console.log(v.arrival.time.low);
      return;
    }
  });
});
var feed = {
  "entity": [{
    "id": "1",
    "is_deleted": false,
    "trip_update": {
      "trip": {
        "trip_id": "009250_L..S",
        "route_id": "L",
        "start_time": null,
        "start_date": "20170512",
        "schedule_relationship": null,
        ".nyct_trip_descriptor": {
          "train_id": "0L 0132+8AV/RPY",
          "is_assigned": true,
          "direction": 3
        }
      },
      "vehicle": null,
      "stop_time_update": [{
          "stop_sequence": null,
          "stop_id": "L26S",
          "arrival": {
            "delay": null,
            "time": {
              "low": 1494569453,
              "high": 0,
              "unsigned": false
            },
            "uncertainty": null
          },
          "departure": {
            "delay": null,
            "time": {
              "low": 1494569483,
              "high": 0,
              "unsigned": false
            },
            "uncertainty": null
          },
          "schedule_relationship": 0,
          ".nyct_stop_time_update": {
            "scheduled_track": "1",
            "actual_track": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "stop_sequence": null,
          "stop_id": "L27S",
          "arrival": {
            "delay": null,
            "time": {
              "low": 1494569551,
              "high": 0,
              "unsigned": false
            },
            "uncertainty": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your case is that `feed.entity[0].trip_update.stop_time_update` is array you need to iterate (without index in the end).

Besides, you don't need jQuery, use native js `forEach` instead:

```
feed.entity[0].trip_update.stop_time_update.forEach(function(e){
   if (e.stop_id == "L02N") {
       console.log(v.arrival.time.low);
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with keys equal to stop names, and values equal to timestamps. Example:

```js
const a ={"entity":[{"id":"1","is_deleted":false,"trip_update":{"trip":{"trip_id":"009250_L..S","route_id":"L","start_time":null,"start_date":"20170512","schedule_relationship":null,".nyct_trip_descriptor":{"train_id":"0L0132+8AV/RPY","is_assigned":true,"direction":3}},"vehicle":null,"stop_time_update":[{"stop_sequence":null,"stop_id":"L26S","arrival":{"delay":null,"time":{"low":1494569453,"high":0,"unsigned":false},"uncertainty":null},"departure":{"delay":null,"time":{"low":1494569483,"high":0,"unsigned":false},"uncertainty":null},"schedule_relationship":0,".nyct_stop_time_update":{"scheduled_track":"1","actual_track":"1"}},{"stop_sequence":null,"stop_id":"L27S","arrival":{"delay":null,"time":{"low":1494569551,"high":0,"unsigned":false},"uncertainty":null},}]}}]};
                                              
const result = a.entity.reduce((acc, cur, i) => 
  Object.assign(acc, cur.trip_update.stop_time_update && cur.trip_update.stop_time_update.reduce((a, c) => 
    Object.assign(a, {[c.stop_id]: c.arrival.time.low}), {})), {});              

console.log(result)
console.log(result['L26S']) // you can use it like this
```

Comment: Hey I tried using this method but some of the values of stop_time_update are null and I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop_time_update' of null. Do you have any suggestions to skip these stop_time_updates that are null.

Comment: Never mind, I added, if (ent.trip_update != null) before and it works now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @emmodz I've updated my answer to handle this situation when `stop_time_update == null`